# Ansible: ansible_domain or facter_domain - How to get domain value of a hostname mentioned in inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, domain-name, ansible-facts

Ansible 1.9.2 / 1.9.4 
CentOS 6.7

In my invetory file, I have:

```
[zabbix_server]
zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins

[some_other_zabbix_server]
someotherzabbix.dev-blue.project.jenkins ansible_ssh_host=10.120.133.11
```

When I run:

```
ansible -m setup -i hosts zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins
```

It gives me the following error:

**zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins | FAILED => FAILED: No authentication methods available**

In my playbook, I'm trying to get the domain value of the zabbix server which is dev-white.projectname.jenkins. I tried the following but variable which are for showing the domain values are coming as blank/null, why?

**Note:** Value for inventory_hostname is showing correctly!! but domain values for ansible_domain / facter_domain are coming as blank/null value.

```
- debug: msg="My server is= {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]].inventory_hostname }} and domain is= {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]].ansible_domain }} --- {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]]['inventory_hostname'] }} -- {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]]['ansible_domain'] }} -- -- {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]]['facter_domain'] }}"
```

Tried the above code for some_other_zabbix_server group variable (where ansible_ssh_host variable is set), still no values are coming for showing its domain. **PS:** *ansible_ssh_host property will be deprecated in newer Ansible versions*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to split and join all parts except the first part.

```
  - debug: var="{{ groups['zabbix_server'][0].split('.')[1:] | join('.') }}"
```

Result:

```
  "dev-white.projectname.jenkins"
```

Comment: No need for join just use `.split('.', 1)[1]`